# How do I declare constants in a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll

I am just getting acquainted to creating libraries for the first time in my life, and right now I have a problem.

```
//lib.h
#ifdef DLL_EXPORT
    #define DECLDIR __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DECLDIR __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
...
extern "C" {
    DECLDIR const double MAX_CALC_DUR = 60;
    DECLDIR int stoi(string input);    // C++11 not available on the Code::Blocks version I'm given to work with
}
```

Applying what I learnt from this [tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c9855/DLL-Tutorial-For-Beginners.htm), I've managed to successfully build the library with only `stoi()` inside and linked it to other projects for use. Now, I want to add in a constant as seen in the code above. However, I receive the following error:

```
external linkage required for symbol 'MAX_CALC_DUR' because of 'dllexport' attribute
```

Research led me to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690538/problems-compiling-dll-using-gcc-on-windows), which suggests the problem may have something to do with `MAX_CALC_DUR` essentially being equivalent to static. However, I know there are constants defined in the standard library, so what is the correct way to define a constant in DLL?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply omit `DECLDIR`. Since `MAX_CALC_DUR` has internal linkage (because it's `const`), every file which includes the header will then get its own private copy as it normally would, and everything will work just fine.

You don't need to export something from a DLL if it can be inserted into client code directly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand DLL well yet. what does it mean to export from a DLL? Why is it needed for my `stoi()` function but not `MAX_CALC_DUR`?

Comment: @thegreatjedi Exporting a symbol from a DLL means making it available to clients of the DLL. That's what the `__declspec(dllexport)` specifier does. You need to do this for entities with external linkage (non-static functions and non-static variables) which are declared in the DLL's headers, but defined in the DLL itself. Without it, the definition would be inaccessible to client code (you'd get linker errors from using them). A symbol with internal linkage (such as a static or `const` variable) doesn't need that; as usual, it can exist in all object files including its definition.

Comment: You can think of it this way: `stoi` is defined inside the DLL (in one of its source files), so it must be exported. `MAX_CALC_DUR`, on the other hand, is not defined inside the DLL, it's defined in the header which gets included by clients directly. So there's nothing inside the DLL which would need exporting for that.